# Call handler without specifying ashx file on URL?

Tags: c#, handler, ashx, webapi

I have a handler called `HandlerGeoserver`

If I call `localhost:55000/HandlerGeoserver.ashx` on runtime everything works fine. I need to remove the `HandlerGeoserver.ashx` text from the URL, and make the request to be handled by the handler.

> `localhost:55000/`  fires the `HandlerGeoserver.ashx`

Is this possible?

- If not, an option I considered is to set via web.config to route `/` routes to `handlerGeoserver.ashx`, but don't know if this is possible.
- Another option I considered was to combine the handler with webapi, so that when calling a route from the api (`localhost:55000/`), the controller redirects the call to the handler. Do you think this could be a good approximation?

Comment: There is also [ASP.NET FriendlyUrls](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved creating a rewrite rule on my `web.config` as following:

```xml
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule>
         <match url="/" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="HandlerGeoserver.ashx" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It is the simplest and most effective solution I found.